# Unexpected NULLs in JOIN query

Tags: sql, join

I am using 3 tables in the query: 2 with `INNER JOIN` and the 3rd with `LEFT JOIN`.

However, I am getting some `NULL`records while the `LEFT JOIN` condition is executing. There are coming from the Purchase line(PL_ TABLE)`which should not be the case.

Can any one recommend the change in the query to replace `NULL` values in the record with actual values?

Sorry, I could not find any option to attach the sample table data.

**The Query**

```
SELECT
    pih.[PO Number], 
    pih.[Pre-Assigned No_] as [Invoice No],
    pil.[Document No_],
    pil.[Description] as [Reason For Discrepency],
    pil.[Line No_],
    pl.[No_] as [Item No],
    pl.[Vendor Item No_],
    pl.[Order Date],
    pil.[Posting Date],
    pil.[Expected Receipt Date],
    pih.[Notes] as [Header Notes],
    pil.[No_] as [G/L Account No],
    pih.[Buy-from Vendor No_],
    pih.[Buy-from Vendor Name],
    Pil.Quantity as [Inv Qty From InvoiceLine], 
    pil.[Amount Including VAT] as [Inv Value From InvoiceLine], 
    pl.Quantity as [PO Quantity From Purchaseline], 
    pl.[Quantity Received] as [Received Qty From PurchaseLine],
    pl.[Quantity Invoiced] as [Invoiced Qty From PurchaseLine] ,
    pl.[Amount Including VAT] as [PO Value From PurchaseLine]
FROM 
    [Purch_ Inv_ Line] pil
    INNER JOIN Purch_ Inv_ Header] pih
        ON pil.[Document No_] = pih.[No_]
    LEFT JOIN [Purchase Line] pl 
        ON pih.[PO Number]=pl.[Document No_] and pl.[Line No_]=pil.[Line No_]
WHERE 
    PIL.[Document No_] IN
    (
        SELECT distinct pil.[Document No_] FROM   
            Purch_ Inv_ Line] pil 
        WHERE piL.[No_] in ('700xxx','700xxx','17xxxxx') and pil.[Posting Date] >=getdate()-7
    )
    AND piL.[Type]='1'
```

Comment: If you do a `LEFT JOIN` and there is no data in your joined table that matches your join criteria, those columns will be `NULL`. It's impossible to say what's wrong without sample data and and expected and actual output.

Answer (score 0):

There might be 2 reasons why you are getting `NULL` values:

- Values of columns in **[Purchase line]** table are actually `NULL`
- There are no matching rows in **[Purchase line]** table for rows that are `NULL`. This is how [LEFT JOIN](https://www.google.no/search?q=LEFT%20JOIN&oq=LEFT%20JOIN) works

If you want to get only matching rows, then change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` - however then your result set will not contain rows from **[Purch_ Inv_ Line]** and **[Purch_ Inv_ Header]** where there are not matching **[Purchase line]** rows.

If you want to give default values to `NULL` values you can do it using `ISNULL`:

```
ISNULL(pl.[Amount Including VAT], 0) as [PO Value From PurchaseLine]
```